# Perform action in TagViews inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, taglist

I am using TaglistView to show tags in UITableViewCell. https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Now need to get id for the tag selected on a particular index path.

eg: JSON array is in format:

Index 0 : [{ name: "abc",
      value: "11"
},{ name: "c",
      value: "12"}]

Index 1 : [{ name: "abcd",
      value: "21"
},{ name: "abcde",
      value: "22"
}]

Index 2 : [{ name: "abcde",
      value: "31"
}, { name: "abcde",
      value: "32"
}]

Code that I have used for adding taglist:

```
func configureCell (tableView: UITableView, cell: PlaylistCell, indexPath: IndexPath){

        // Setup TagView
        cell.tagListView.removeAllTags()
        for tag in array?[indexPath.row].sponsoredBy ?? [] {
            cell.tagListView.addTag(tag.name ?? "")
        }
        cell.tagListView.delegate = self


    }
```

Now Taglist Delegate method:

```
func tagPressed(_ title: String, tagView: TagView, sender: TagListView) {
        print("Tag pressed: \(title)")
    }
```

I am getting name of tag pressed, but need to get value of the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a tag to `tagListView` with `indexPath.row`  like in cellForRow

```
tagListView.tag == indexPath.row
```

Now Taglist Delegate method:

```
func tagPressed(_ title: String, tagView: TagView, sender: TagListView) {
    let yourObject = yourArrayOfTagListContainer[tagView.tag]

    print("Tag pressed: \(yourObject.value)")
}
```

Hope it helps